# Get the value of label assigned by jquery in a button click

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap v3.3 Modal and I assign a value to a label with jquery, how can i get the value of the assigned lable with button_click in c#?
I can pass the value to the text box, I am able to get the value from the textbox, but not from the lable.
I am using the below code.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
               <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" runat="server"></h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="recipient-name" id="lblOldValue" class="control-label" runat="server">Brand:</label>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtUpdate" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Save" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click"/>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
        var recipient = button.data('whatever'); // Extract info from data-* attributes

        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('Edit: ' + recipient);
        modal.find('modal-body lable').val(recipient);
        modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient);
    });

protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string newValue = txtUpdate.Text;
    string oldValue = lblOldValue.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: so do you know how to do a simple google search `get the value of a label in jquery` tons of hits come back in less than 1 second..

Comment: I have already searched and tried different solutions, but I couldn't find any solution that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using a hidden field.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID = "hfName" runat = "server" />

document.getElementById("<%=hfName.ClientID %>").value = recipient;

string oldValue = Request.Form[hfName.UniqueID];
```